# Unable to find field "player_1_name" that is not disabled

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I just started this code by a walkthrough that I've been given. And my feature test should work but it gives me this error:

## `Unable to find field "player_1_name" that is not disabled`

I have tried changing the quotes, the path, using [], and still giving me the same error.

- My ruby version.
  ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
- Also, I am using shotgun, sinatra, apart from Rspec and capybara.
  In the code below I'll specify which file are each code.

```
#features/entre_names_spec.rp

feature "Enter names" do
  scenario "submitting names" do
    visit('/')
    fill_in "player_1_name", with: 'Dave'
    fill_in "player_2_name", with: 'Mittens'
    click_button 'Submit'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Dave vs. Mittens'
  end
end
```

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class Battle < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'Testing infrastructure working!'
  end

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  post '/names' do
    @player_1_name = params[:player_1_name]
    @player_2_name = params[:player_2_name]
    erb :play
  end

  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

```
views/index.erb
<form action= "names" method= "post">
  <input type= "text" name= "player_1_name">
  <input type= "text" name= "player_2_name">
  <input type= "submit" value= "Submit">
</form>
```

```
#views/play.erb
<%= @player_1_name %> vs. <% @player_2_name %>
```

```
Failures:

  1) Enter names submitting names
     Failure/Error: fill_in "player_1_name", with: "Dave"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "player_1_name" that is not disabled
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:296:in `block in synced_resolve'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:83:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:287:in `synced_resolve'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:52:in `find'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:91:in `fill_in'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:749:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /Users/student/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/enter_names_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.07645 seconds (files took 0.94706 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/enter_names_spec.rb:2 # Enter names submitting names
```

Comment: Cannot find `player_1_name`. Because it's not the path /names you visited in the test. I thingk, if you do `visit('/names')`, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi Demir, I've tried that already and didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I think there's an error in the path. What is the path to this view? Could it be '/battles' or '/battle/names' ?

Comment: Try to `save_and_open_page` after calling `visit` and inspect the page under test in your browser. Maybe the elements are missing or you are simply on the wrong page.

Comment: Setting aside the test for a minute, what happens when you visit the root path (`/`) in a browser? Do you see the form you expect to be there?

Comment: Yes, in the homepage I expect to see `'Testing infrastructure working!'`, as I said, I tried changing the path to /names and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that if you visit the root path, you'll see `Testing infrastructure working!`. That's because `get '/'` is defined twice, and in my version of Sinatra (v2.0.5), the first declaration wins.

Here's a simple version of this server that renders the form. It should pass the test:

```rb
# app.rb

require 'sinatra'

# get '/' defined once
get '/' do
  erb :index
end

post '/names' do
  @player_1_name = params[:player_1_name]
  @player_2_name = params[:player_2_name]
  erb :play
end
```

Run with:

```
$ ruby app.rb
```

Caveat: you'll have to add a second equals sign to the play view as well, so ERB knows `@player_2_name` is a Ruby expression.

```
# views/play.erb

<%= @player_1_name %> vs. <%= @player_2_name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It is saying 'disabled' because the .erb is not in the correct location in your directory. It should be saved in a 'views' folder.